# Examples of $X$ halts IFF $Y$ does not halt?

Tags: algorithms, examples-counterexamples, stopping-times, turing-machines

Let $X,Y$ be algorithms that accept an ordered set of positive integers as input.

What are examples of $X$ halts if and only if $Y$ does not halt ?

Im aware that the general halting problem is undecidable.

Comment: Stopping = halting or not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Take any problem that is known to be decidable, i.e. a statement $S(s)$ depending on the input $s$ such that it is known that for every $s$, either $S(s)$ or $\neg S(s)$ is provable (in a given consistent formal system).  Let $X$ search all finite sequences of statements of the system for proofs of $S(s)$, halting if it finds one, and similarly let $Y$ search for proofs of $\neg S(s)$, halting if it finds one.

Comment: Ok but say the statement is that the diophantine can be solved ; Then S(s) halts When a search algorithm X finds a solution , but Then What is Y ??

Comment: If "can be solved" means there is always a solution, Y is a program that never halts.  If "can be solved" means either there is a solution or there is a certificate that there is no solution, then Y is a program that looks for a certificate that there is no solution.